# Spring batch connectivity to vertica DB

Tags: spring-batch, vertica

I am trying to connect Vertica using Spring batch but getting excception from Vertica DB.

Can I connect to Vertica DB using Spring batch. Tried to search on on net but didn't find any example.

Comment: Can you connect to your db using standard spring (spring-jdbc for example)? Which error did you get from batch?

Comment: Yes I can connect. The problem I am facing is spring batch jar contains some .sql file corresponding to each DB. For eg DB2.sql,  but for Vertica there is no sql file. I tried to create it but still got exception from DB. The Exception I am getting is Job_Instance table doesnt exist. Tried to create but could't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your database using [jdbc:initialize-database](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch12s09.html): use your custim vertica db script contains  springbatch metadata tables creation and all should be fine.

Comment: I do agree with you but how can I create those tables? any idea? I tried to copy from .sql file all the tables and initiliaze it but getting exceptiob like..last_insert_id doesnt exist.

Comment: IDK vertica db sql syntax; just look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html) and try to replicate metadata tables structure.